# Firebase REST API Method: projects.databases.documents.runAggregationQuery not working

Tags: rest, google-cloud-firestore

No matter what I try, I always get errors when trying to make an API Call using runAggregationQuery to sum up the field `number` of the `a_test` collection. When using the Cloud Firestore API Explorer, I receive the same responses as in my app. It is as the documentation states and as the API Explorer shows it. I just need to add `"structuredAggregationQuery": {}` to the request body, and I receive this error. But this is according to the documentation. As soon as I change anything that is not part of the documentation, I receive the warning that it is an invalid parameter, which is why I don't understand why this is not working.

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"structuredAggregationQuery\" at 'document': Cannot find field.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "field": "document",
            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"structuredAggregationQuery\" at 'document': Cannot find field."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried using the REST API to get a document and this worked fine. It doesn't matter if I complete the request body or use different strings, I always receive this output.